# How to get comments of facebook photo using graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

What I am trying to do is to display all the images of user with comments and likes on my website. I can get all images successfully but can't get comments.

```
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if($user)
{
  $photo = $facebook->api("/".231321313."?fields=comments,likes", array("access_token" => $facebook->getAccessToken());
  var_dump($photo);
}
```

where **231321313** is my photo id, Please help i am stuck here.

**result:** I am only getting photo details not comments..

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/
tells me that photo comments can be found in /PHOTO_ID/comments

So should be something like this:

```
$photo_comments = $facebook->api("/". $photo->id ."/comments", array("access_token" => $facebook->getAccessToken());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use an FQL query to get the comments, providing the `object_id` field with the object ID of a photo. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/

Note the following section, for it is relevant and you probably won't like it:

> […] for photos and albums, the object_id must be queried from
>   the photo and album FQL tables. Note that in the photo and album
>   tables, object_id is a different field from pid and aid.